# css inside a jquery function

Tags: jquery, css

With a lot of help from fellow members I have 99.9% completed a script I am working. All that I have left is to give the row inside my jquery a bottom border. I have tried all sorts of ways of doing this and failed. I am not sure where to start with this, can anyone help, please.

My Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function get_data() {
  $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
  json = json[0].data;
  var tr ;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");

   $('table').append(tr);
  }
  });

}

get_data();
setInterval(get_data,60000)
});
```

Again, many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you tried either the jQuery `.css()` function or just regular CSS? Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Give the row a class and use css rules

Comment: just use regular css.

Comment: Why not tr.css('border-bottom','1px solid black') before appending to table

Comment: Put a class name on the rows and add the css in your css file.  That or just target the rows directly in the css file.  Also, if you are adding more than one row at a time, it is best to create all of them and then just do one append rather than appending each row one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, add `tr.css("border-bottom","1px solid #000");`

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      function get_data() {
      $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
      json = json[0].data;
      var tr ;
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.css("border-bottom","1px solid #000");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + 
      json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + 
      json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + 
      json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");
      $('table').append(tr);
       }
       });
       }
       get_data();
       setInterval(get_data,60000)
       });
```